# Files in Program files folder vanished

Tags: windows-7, directory, program-files

I have saved few files in Program files.When I checked again, the files are not seen. I tried searching the system with the file name, but it is not found. 
How did the files disappear? 
And is there a way to recover the files?

Comment: See "[UAC virtualization](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx)."

Comment: I tried with this, but I couldn't find the file in C:\Users\MyUserAccount\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files.